# How to use ffmpeg to selectively replace a specific color with another color in videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors

Some of my videos have a very eye-hurting white color in them, like the white color in clouds. I looked for ways, using ffmpeg, to filter out and then change only the white color to something a little gray. I could not find a solution except this one:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf eq=gamma_b=0.5 output.mp4
```

Which changes the strong white color to something yellowish and eye-friendly. The problem is that this filter alters all the video colors.

What I want to change is only the white color and not all other colors.

Comment: See http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#selectivecolor-1

Comment: @Gyan thanks, i am trying to figure out a script for what i need.

Answer (score 2):

using @Gyan indication and converting grey color code to CMYK, i come up with this ffmpeg script:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "selectivecolor=whites=0 0 0 .12" output.mp4
```

the .12 means 12% of black, to be increased or decreased according to one's need but must be between -1 and +1.